How can I group certain from datetime & to datetime to get the idle time of the time?
How do I get expected output - idle time based on this raw data?
Raw data



Timein
TimeOut




2024-09-01 10:00:00
2024-09-01 11:00:00


2024-09-01 10:00:00
2024-09-01 12:00:00


2024-09-01 10:20:00
2024-09-01 13:00:00


2024-09-01 14:00:00
2024-09-01 15:00:00


2024-09-01 15:30:00
2024-09-01 16:00:00



Expected output



Timein
TimeOut
Duration
IdleTime




2024-09-01 10:00:00
2024-09-01 11:00:00
60min
0min


2024-09-01 10:00:00
2024-09-01 12:00:00
120min
0min


2024-09-01 10:20:00
2024-09-01 13:00:00
160min
0min


2024-09-01 14:00:00
2024-09-01 15:00:00
120min
60min


2024-09-01 15:30:00
2024-09-01 16:00:00
30min
30min



I achieved till duration but struggling with idle time.
This is the query I wrote :
SELECT
    TimeIn, TimeOut, 
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Timein, Timeout) AS duration
FROM
    [test_idletime]


Please read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Sounds like you need to get previous TimeOut to calculate IdleTime. LAG-function might be in order for that

Actually if you notice from 10am to 13pm its a continious slab. then there is 1hr/60min gap. then started again form 14pm to 15pm. want to get this 1hr/60min gap info as idletime

I would read this documentation about the lag function

With overlapping time ranges, you might have some weird overlap scenarios where the last prior TimeOut is not from the immediately preceding row (as sorted by TimeIn). Consider the time ranges: 09:00-10:30, 09:15-10:15, 09:30-10:00, 11:00-12:00. The last row's calculated IdleTime should be 30 minutes, not 60 minutes. You may need to calculate and compare the current TimeIn against the MAX(TimeOut)where priorTimeIn< currentTimeIn`.

Well, i tried with LAG it also worked with some other concept(MaxPriorTime/GREATEST()). Thanks everyone.

With overlapping time ranges, you might have some weird overlap scenarios where the last prior TimeOut is not from the immediately preceding row (as sorted by TimeIn). Consider the time ranges: 09:00-10:30, 09:15-10:15, 09:30-10:00, 11:00-12:00. The last row's calculated IdleTime should be 30 minutes, not 60 minutes.
To handle this, you need to calculate and compare the current TimeIn against the MAX(TimeOut) where prior TimeIn < current TimeIn. This can be done using an appropriately constrained window function to calculate the running MAX(TimeOut) in a nested query or CTE, with IdleTime calculated in the outer/final query.
SELECT
    TimeIn, TimeOut, MaxPriorTimeOut,
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, TimeIn, TimeOut) as Duration,
    GREATEST(0, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, MaxPriorTimeOut, TimeIn)) as IdleTime
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        MAX(TimeOut) OVER(
               ORDER BY TimeIn
               ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
            )AS MaxPriorTimeOut
    FROM Data
) T
ORDER BY TimeIn

The GREATEST() function is available in SQL Server 2022 and later. For earlier versions, you can use a CASE expression to achieve the same results.
    CASE WHEN MaxPriorTimeOut < TimeIn
        THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, MaxPriorTimeOut, TimeIn)
        ELSE 0 END as IdleTime

Results (with some extra test data):



TimeIn
TimeOut
MaxPriorTimeOut
Duration
IdleTime




2024-09-01 10:00
2024-09-01 11:00
null
60
0


2024-09-01 10:00
2024-09-01 12:00
2024-09-01 11:00
120
0


2024-09-01 10:20
2024-09-01 13:00
2024-09-01 12:00
160
0


2024-09-01 14:00
2024-09-01 15:00
2024-09-01 13:00
60
60


2024-09-01 15:30
2024-09-01 16:00
2024-09-01 15:00
30
30


2024-09-02 09:00
2024-09-02 10:30
2024-09-01 16:00
90
1020


2024-09-02 09:15
2024-09-02 10:15
2024-09-02 10:30
60
0


2024-09-02 09:30
2024-09-02 10:00
2024-09-02 10:30
30
0


2024-09-02 11:00
2024-09-02 12:00
2024-09-02 10:30
60
30


2024-09-03 08:00
2024-09-03 09:00
2024-09-02 12:00
60
1200


2024-09-03 10:00
2024-09-03 12:00
2024-09-03 09:00
120
60


2024-09-03 10:30
2024-09-03 11:30
2024-09-03 12:00
60
0



See this db<>fiddle for a demo.

Thanks a lot, by this time i also developed one which match the exact result once i run your and mine one <3

try it to see the same result.
SELECT TimeIn,TimeOut, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Timein, Timeout)  as duration,
case when DATEDIFF(MINUTE, TimeIn, lag(TimeOut) OVER (ORDER BY timeout asc))  < 0
then SUBSTRING(Convert(varchar, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, TimeIn, lag(TimeOut) OVER (ORDER BY timeout))) , 2, 100) -- value came as - to remove - added substing
else '0' end as idletime
FROM [test_idletime]

Here's what I found:

SELECT TimeIn,TimeOut, 
  DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Timein, Timeout)  as duration,
  case when DATEDIFF(MINUTE, TimeIn, lag(TimeOut) OVER (ORDER BY timeout asc))  < 0 
    then SUBSTRING(Convert(varchar, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, TimeIn
                    , lag(TimeOut) OVER (ORDER BY timeout))) 
     , 2, 100) -- value came as - to remove - added substing
  else '0' end as idletime
FROM [test_idletime]


I initially thought you may have nailed it, but I found a case 08:00-09:00, 10:00-12:00, 10:30-11:30 that calculates a 90 minute IdleTime (09:00...10:30) instead of the expected 60 minute IdleTime (09:00...10:00) . I don't think LAG() can be reliably used for the general case that has overlapping ranges. fiddle.

Side note: In most cases, it is best to leave numbers as numbers and not cast to text in a query unless absolutely necessary. Leave formatting to the presentation layer. For the above query, drop the Convert(varchar, ...) and SUBSTRING(...) operations and change '0' to 0.  The negative values can be fixed by swapping the from/to parameters in the DATEDIFF() function. The < 0 would then change to a > 0. -- case when DATEDIFF(MINUTE, lag(TimeOut) OVER (ORDER BY timeout asc), TimeIn) > 0  then DATEDIFF(MINUTE, lag(TimeOut) OVER (ORDER BY timeout), TimeIn) else 0 end as idletime

T N, Atually you are right i didn't notice this. Thank you so much for your kind feedback. Will follow your guidline too.

EJoshuaS, i will follow your guideline also, as i'm new here so didn't understand the manner/practice of this platform for question/answer. Thanks for your feedback
